# How to render a view say View_b from a partial page say partial_a which have been called/rendered in a view say view_a?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am calling a view from an Action Item "Index". This "Index" view is rendering one partial view say Partial_a internally.
@Html.Partial("Partial_a");

Partial_a have a button and "on-click" using Ajax calls an Action Item "Search" under same controller. So I expect it to return me "Search" view. But it does not. It returns the same old view "Index" from where it was rendered initially. I can find a reason for this. 
But can anyone please tell me how do I return the view "Search" from the partial view "Partial_a" which is rendered internally from a different view "Index".

Comment: AJAX calls stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, create an action link of use javascript `window.location.href = '/...`

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen say if you want to redirect then use

```
  window.location.href = '/...'
```

and if you want to do it on the same page to get only html of that Partial View  then just make an Ajax Call

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/YourController/YourAction',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Div').html(data);                    
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
```

and in Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {            
        return PartialView(ob);
    }
```

Comment: Adding to the above requirement, I write here the main requirement. I have a textbox which will get you any product which you want to search. Now on clicking on "Search" button, I need to get this input from user and redirect it to a different view displaying the data from database. How to get this Search item requested by user if I use an "Action Link" in my view. If I am not using Ajax, I am not able to pass form data to controller. Is there any logic using which I can send this input from user data to controller?